# android menu navigation options

Tags: android, menu, navigation

Can you please let me know on various possibilities or best options for handling navigation on android application. Links to sample will be very much helpful, if possible. Its to do the following:

Application starts with a splash screen.
The splash screen ends to display the following choices:

- Post a Quote
- List my Quotes
- List all Quotes
- Search for Quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Romain Guy elaborates on a few things you can do with ListView / GridView](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/22/why-is-my-list-black-an-android-optimization/)

A ListView or a GridView is probably how I would go. But you could of course create a layout of your own and render your own buttons just about wherever.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally recommended to avoid a splash screen and instead use the menu functionality
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Choose a default activity which will be the one most users will use (in your case I assume List My Quotes). The rest of the activities are available through the menu.